# What is a modern service to create a feed from (rarely-changing) static sites?

Tags: getstream-io

I used Page2RSS years ago to quickly find papers academics post on their personal websites (often more and before posting on repositories that generate feeds). That service is gone, but a replacement would be a huge draw for me to pick up RSS again, e.g. using Winds from the good people behind Stream.

Is there a modern solution to achieve the same result?